# How to restore mails from unix mbox file to imap server?

Tags: imap, mutt, mbox

I accidentally let mutt to move all read emails from the server to local mbox file. How to restore mails to the server?

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing if/how you can do this with other clients, e.g. Thunderbird...

Comment: Almost all IMAP clients let you move mail back and forth from/to the IMAP server. So you would just drag the messages back to IMAP. (Although Thunderbird doesn't auto-move your mail to `~/mbox`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the mbox file in mutt (`mutt -f ~/mbox` or the <kbd>c</kbd> key), tag all messages (<kbd>T</kbd>), move them back (<kbd>;</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd>).